Make the pipeline fail if a specific sentence appears in the log – Find a substring, but ignore a specific substring
In my first question, the goal was to intentionally make the CI/CD pipeline fail if a transformation is not possible in the Web.Live.Config. I had to save the build in a variable. If a transformation is not possible,
the string "No element in the source document matches" appears in the log. But: Although there is no key with "connectionString" in the config files, strangely the string "No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings'" appears. I wanted to ignore it.
Can someone help me search the log for a string but ignore the "No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings'"? I tried -ne, -notmatch and -notlike, but it didn't help.
Even though the string " ... warning : No element in the source document matches '/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='anotherKEY']'" appears, the pipeline does not fail.
I'm new to PowerShell, and I would appreciate your assistance.
-  echo "Verifying build…"
- |
 $msbuildOutput = & $MSBUILD_PATH "$Our_ASMX_PROJECT_PATH" /Target:Rebuild /property:Configuration=Live /T:Package 
 $pattern = "No element in the source document matches"
 $ignorePattern = "No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings'" # ignore the specific message
 $relevantMatches = $pattern | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch $ignorePattern }
 if ($relevantMatches)
 {
    Write-Host "Build failed due to missing configuration key or transformation."
    exit 1
 }

Another attempt:
-  echo "Verifying build…"
- |
 $msbuildOutput = & $MSBUILD_PATH "$Our_ASMX_PROJECT_PATH" /Target:Rebuild /property:Configuration=Live /T:Package 
 $pattern = "No element in the source document matches"
 $ignorePattern = "No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings'" # ignore the specific message
 $matches = $msbuildOutput | Select-String -Pattern $pattern | ForEach-Object { $_.Line }
 $relevantMatches = $matches | Where-Object { $_.Line -notlike "*$ignorePattern*" }
 if ($relevantMatches)
 {
    Write-Host "Build failed due to missing configuration key or transformation."
    exit 1
 }

Attempt 7/22/2024
- |
 Write-Host "Verifying build…"
 $msbuildOutput = & $MSBUILD_PATH "$Our_ASMX_PROJECT_PATH" /Target:Rebuild /property:Configuration=Demo /T:Package 
 $pattern = "No element in the source document matches"
 $IgnorePattern = "No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings'"
 # Split the long string into an array of lines
 $msbuildOutputLines = $msbuildOutput -split "(\r\n)"
 $errors = $msbuildOutputLines | Where-Object { $_ -like "*$pattern*" -and $_ -notlike "*$IgnorePattern*" }
 if ($errors)
 {
   Write-Host "Build failed due to missing configuration key or transformation."
   exit 1
 }

07/26/2024 Output (anonymised, excerpt)
''
''
'"D:\gitlab-runner-ps\builds\BuildNumber\0\aNamespace\anotherNamespace\Project\OurDirectory\ProjectName.vbproj" (Rebuild;Package Ziel) (1) ->'
'"D:\gitlab-runner-ps\builds\BuildNumber\0\aNamespace\anotherNamespace\Project\AnotherDirectory\AnotherProjectName.csproj" (Standardziel) (3:3) ->'
'"D:\gitlab-runner-ps\builds\BuildNumber\0\aNamespace\anotherNamespace\Project\EvenAnotherDir\EvenAnotherProjectName" (Standardziel) (13:5) ->'
'  D:\gitlab-runner-ps\builds\BuildNumber\0\aNamespace\anotherNamespace\Project\AnotherDir\FileName.cs(72,30): warning CS0168: Die Variable "e" ist deklariert, wird aber nie verwendet. [D:\gitlab-runner-ps\builds\BuildNumber\0\aNamespace\anotherNamespace\Project\AnotherDir\ProjectName.csproj]'

Edit 07/29/2024 showing errors 
Showing errors:
C:\Windows\TEMP\build_scriptSomeNumber\script.ps1 :
D:\gitlab-runner-ps\builds\AnotherNumber\0\aNamespace\aNamespace\Project\OurProjectPath\Web.Live.config(204,10): warning : No element in the source document matches '/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='THATKEY']'
[D:\gitlab-runner-ps\builds\AnotherNumber\0\aNamespace\aNamespace\Project\Namespace\OurProjectPath.vbproj]
D:\gitlab-runner-ps\builds\AnotherNumber\0\aNamespace\aNamespace\Project\OurCompany.ANamespace.Project.AsmxService\Web.Live.config(204,10): warning : No element in the source document matches '/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='THATKEY']' 
[D:\gitlab-runnerps\builds\AnotherNumber\0\aNamespace\aNamespace\Project\OurCompany.ANamespace.Project.AsmxService\OurProjectPath.vbproj]
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ C:\Windows\TEMP\build_scriptSomeNumber\script.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,script.ps1



Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, show the code where is defined $matches. Moreover, share (sanitized if necessary) a relevant part of the log file…

I don't have a log file, and I mustn't write one.

Prefix your script with the Set-StrictMode -Version latest line to see some (hidden) errors, keeping $ErrorActionPreference default value (Continue)…

Assuming each warning will be in a separate line you can use this:
$MsBuildOutput = & $MSBUILD_PATH "$Our_ASMX_PROJECT_PATH" /Target:Rebuild /property:Configuration=Live /T:Package 
$pattern = "No element in the source document matches"
$IgnorePattern = "No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings'"
$errors = $MsBuildOutput -split "`n" | where { $_ -notlike "*$IgnorePattern*" -and $_ -like "*$pattern*" }
if ($errors) { Write-Error -ErrorAction Stop -Message "$errors" }

This code assumes that each warning is on a separate line.

Hello, your solution works in an online tool. When I remove "No element in the source document matches", the if block is not executed, and when I add "No element in the source document matches", it is executed. However, in the actual pipeline, the build does not fail in either case.
Additionally, I have written some more code today, which I will edit into my question shortly. Here too, the pipeline does not fail.

@Daniel So your saying that Write-Error -ErrorAction Stop is exuded but the pipeline does not fail?

The If block is not executed, as if §errors was not true

@Daniel so is this port $errors = $MsBuildOutput | where { $_ -notlike "*$IgnorePattern*" -and $_ -like $pattern } not working?  how is the results in $MsBuildOutput ? is it multi strings or one string ?  and if so, is it one line or a multi line string ?

Yes, there is something assigned to $errors because $MsBuildOutput returns something. It is one multi-line string. I have printed the output as a test.

@Daniel if its one multi-line string you will need to split it first, I updated my answer.

I did split already. See Attempt 7/22/2024 in my question.

@Daniel So double check if there is something in $errors, run $errors | Out-Host and show us the results.

Ok, I have now written an excerpt of the output into the question.

@Daniel Looks that you show the output of $MsBuildOutput but what is the output of $errors or $MsBuildOutput -split "`n" | where { $_ -notlike "*$IgnorePattern*" -and $_ -like "*$pattern*" } ?

the error is System.Object[]" cannot be converted to the type "System.String" required for the parameter "Message". The specified method is not supported.

@Daniel Ok I updated the code, I changed $errors to "$errors".

Hey y y, I have added the error output to my question. The error message only mentions an issue at line 1, character 1... @y-y

@Daniel OK, looks great, PowerShell catches the the lines with warning : No element in the source document matches '/configuration/appSettings/ and ignores the line with No element in the source document matches '/configuration/connectionStrings and Write-Error actually throws a termination error, so what is your problem now ?

Hey @y-y, your code works now. When a key in the LiveConfig is not found, the error message appears, and the pipeline fails as expected. I added Write-Host "Build failed due to missing configuration key or transformation." to the code. If no key is missing, the pipeline runs successfully, despite the message with /configuration/connectionStrings. This is good. Thank you for your help and for your persistent comments over the past few days. My problem a few days ago was that the pipeline would pass even if a key was missing.
